# Can't fix Infinite Loop

Tags: vba, excel, infinite-loop

As the title states my msgbox within my userform is stuck in an infinite loop.

I decided to include every command button code there is on this form in case it will help to solve this problem. Also there is also one textbox as well. I've tried various types of loops except the For Loop because every For Loop example I have seen has a counter or some form of increment formula.

What I would like to happen in my loop is if the user clicks on the command button labeled open and `txtbxSelectFile.value = ""` then display the message box and keep doing this every time the `cmdbtnOpen_Click` is `true` and `txtbxSelectFile.value = ""`.

The only thing that came close to working, was the `If ... Then` conditional statement but it would not loop. It would only run once and then continued to the Else condition. Or maybe a better explanation would be if the user keeps clicking the open button and there is nothing in the textbox then keep displaying the message box.

The value from the textbox is supposed to come from a file browse button. When the user clicks the browse button a file dialog opens so the user can locate the file they want to open.

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
    'myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select a File.")

    Dim fname As String
    Dim fpath As String

    fpath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .InitialFileName = fpath
        .ButtonName = "Get File Name"
        .Title = "File Selection"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xl; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlb; *.xlam; *.xltx; *.xltm; *.xls; *.xla; *.xlt; *.xlm; *.xlw"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show = True Then
            fname = .SelectedItems(1)
            Me.txtbxSelectFile.Text = fname
        Else
            MsgBox "Operation Canceled"
            Unload Me
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub cmdbtnOpen_Click()
    Do While txtbxSelectFile = ""
        MsgBox "Please Select a file", vbOKOnly, "No File Selected"
    Loop

    Workbooks.Open Me.txtbxSelectFile
    Unload Me
    selectRangefrm.Show
End Sub
```

I really hope my explanation makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding a `cmdBrowse_Click` between your `MsgBox` and the `Loop` line. • Right now your loop only repeatedly shows a message box but doesn't give the user a chance to select a file.

Comment: You may also want to remove the loop and simply exit the sub with a message when no file was selected, to allow the user to cancel the operation if needed.

Comment: Your right. So how would I add a cmdBrowse_Click to the loop. Do I just add "cmdBrowse_Click" under the message box? Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Yes, just add `cmdBrowse_Click` after the `MsgBox` line in your `cmdbtnOpen_Click` sub

Answer (score 0):

How about a slightly different approach? Why not make the `.Enabled` property of the Open button dependent upon the value of `txtbxSelectFile`?

That way, the Open button can't be pressed until a value sits in `txtbxSelectFile`.

In design mode, change the property of the Open button: set `.Enabled` to `False` and then use:

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
    'myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select a File.")

    Dim fname As String
    Dim fpath As String

    fpath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .InitialFileName = fpath
        .ButtonName = "Get File Name"
        .Title = "File Selection"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xl; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlb; *.xlam; *.xltx; *.xltm; *.xls; *.xla; *.xlt; *.xlm; *.xlw"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show = True Then
            fname = .SelectedItems(1)
            Me.txtbxSelectFile.Text = fname
        Else
            MsgBox "Operation Canceled"
        End If
        cmdbtnOpen.Enabled = Me.txtbxSelectFile.Text <> ""
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub cmdbtnOpen_Click()
    Workbooks.Open Me.txtbxSelectFile
    Unload Me
    selectRangefrm.Show
End Sub
```